# ColorStateList doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

I am beginner in android, and of course i have a problem with ColorStateList. 
I want to set it to ListView, but it doesn't work, maybe someone know why?

it is declaration of TextView

```
<TextView
android:textColor="@color/text_color"
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/in"
android:onClick="onClick"                
android:clickable="true"
android:duplicateParentState='true'/>
```

and content of text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

It is code from StackOverflow reply, should work :/

Comment: you mean clicking on listview item should change textview color,is it? and it's not working

Comment: Ok, my fault, but, can I change color when I focusing listView ? when I am driving over it ?

Comment: normally whole list item takes the touch such that child views inside list item wont get click states. For passing click state to child view you can use 'listview.setItemsCanFocus(true);' .Normally it is used when we want to use button inside list item(or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting `listview.setItemsCanFocus(true);`